# Usage of that: There are many reasons [that] I am confident [that] I will excel at this job

Tags: that

I always find it hard to see when it's best to use "that". Which of these sounds best?

> There are many reasons I am confident I will excel at this job.
>
> There are many reasons that I am confident I will excel at this job.
>
> There are many reasons I am confident that I will excel at this job.
>
> There are many reasons that I am confident that I will excel at this job.

Are there ways of looking at this that I can apply elsewhere?

Is there a completely different formulation that works better?

Comment: There are many, many questions about the use of "that" and the sound of redundant thats. If you search the site, you'll find some really good answers that/which will help you feel more comfortable with the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There are many reasons **why** I am confident (that) I will excel at this job.*

Comment: That does feel better, is there any kind of rule I can apply to decide between "that" and "why" in other situations?

Comment: Not one I can think of.

Comment: "that" normally replaces the direct complement of the following verb and "to be confident" is intransitive. As one is confident *for* or *about* something, you may say "for which" or "about which" instead of "that" for a grammatically correct sentence with a pronoun.

Comment: And _reason_ is the only head noun that can be modified by a relative clause introduced with _why_. For _how_ there isn't any head noun that works at all -- you have to say _the way he does it_ or _the way that he does it_, but you can't say **the way how he does it*.